# Whats does X of imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3]) stand for, whats the meaning of imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I m working on a preprocessing a data set, i get the error cause of the line
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3]). Which i dont get? I understand imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean"), means replace missing values with mean value both in columns and rows. Then are we trying to fit into the model the data, which is what i dont understand?

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pylot as plt %matplotlib inline

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(font_scale=1.2)

stock=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dulangi/Downloads/winequality-red.csv")
stock.head()

g=sns.lmplot('alcohol','quality',data=stock,height=7, truncate=True, scatter_kws={"s":100})
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)

imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
```

The error i get

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-620c08822929> in <module>
     14 imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)
     15 
---> 16 imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])

NameError: name 'X' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-620c08822929> in <module>
     14 imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)
     15 
---> 16 imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])

NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Comment: Things you could do to improve the quality of your question:    
(1) give a simple, reproducible dataset.    
(2) If you have error log, please share that in separate `code block` making it easier for others to look at if need be.     
(3) Make separate sections with **# headers** and **## subheaders**, `code-blocks`, and other available allowed options for markdown on stackoverflow. This makes your question much more readable and crisp in its presentation.   
(4) If possible provide `expected outcome`, so people could verify and evaluate their answers' effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use imputer from sci-kit library, and that is to fill missing values, we fill missing values using mean or mode of the considered column in data set.

In [:,1:3], the left side before the comma indicates to select all rows in data set, you can even specify a range of rows to select as instead of : say we said 1:10, then it selects first 10 rows.

The right side after the comma indicates to select first 3 column, from 1:3, we can even say just : to indicate select all columns.

Then fit actually stores the mean or mode value as calculated on the training data set,using strategy as we assigned to fill in the missing value, then uses it on test data during the transform.

Refer these to get even better idea

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCMrO_VzeL8&t=515s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oH3wYKvwpJ8&t=1s

https://medium.com/@kanchanardj/jargon-in-python-used-in-data-science-to-laymans-language-part-two-98787cce0928

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean by:
+ `SimpleImputer.fit(X_train)`,
+ `SimpleImputer.transform(X_valid)` or `SimpleImputer.transform(X_test)`?

Let my try answering this question first:

An imputer basically finds missing values and then replaces them based on a strategy. As you can see, in the code-example below, I have used `strategy=mean`, which means that given a data `X_train`, you find the `mean` in each column of it and then replace the missing values by these `mean` values calculated for the respective columns.

Now,once you have performed `SimpleImputer.fit(X_train)`, you already have these `mean` values that you used for imputing. Next, when you apply `SimpleImputer.transform(X_test)`, you are actually also imputing the missing values there by the previously calculated `mean` values.

## Technical Solution

It looks like you are trying to import `Imputer` from `sklearn.preprocessing`. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) of sklearn version 0.21.3 there is nothing such as `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`.

### Instead, use this:

[`sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer)

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Imputation
my_imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputed_X_train = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train))
imputed_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_valid))

# Imputation removed column names; put them back
imputed_X_train.columns = X_train.columns
imputed_X_valid.columns = X_valid.columns
```

### Some useful resources:

I will encourage you to look at these resources.

1. [Kaggle Micro-course: dealing with missing values](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/missing-values)
2. [`sklearn.preprocessing` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)
3. [sklearn Guide on Imputation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html)
4. [`sklearn.impute` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the dataset values into the `X` variable  as I mention below.

If you are running the kernel, make sure that variable values should not be reset in kernel..

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib.pylot as plt %matplotlib inline

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(font_scale=1.2)

stock=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dulangi/Downloads/winequality-red.csv")
stock.head()

g=sns.lmplot('alcohol','quality',data=stock,height=7, truncate=True, scatter_kws={"s":100})
X = stock.iloc[ : , :-1].values 
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem gets solved by defining X as follows, and can introduce y to impute as well
X= stock.iloc[:,0:5].values
y= stock.iloc[:,5].values

Comment: Your main question concerns "Imputer". What you suggested here is specific to your current dataset. It may or may not be applicable to needs of imputing by others. Also, your data is locally available to you. That makes it `unavailable` for others if they wish to replicate the problem. However, if you suggest of a method which is generic in nature, so that other visitor of this question can make use of it, that will be great.